# Balland - SABR goes normal

Tags: stochastic-calculus, derivatives, sabr, derivation

**To summarise this very long post :** please help me understand the undetailed proof of the quoted paper. I am not comfortable using a result I do not fully understand.

I am reading Balland & Tran [SABR goes normal](https://www.risk.net/derivatives/interest-rate-derivatives/2269613/sabr-goes-normal) paper and struggle to understand the computations from the first section (equivalent SABR local volatility).

His notations for a general LSV model with lognormal stochastic volatility is
$$
\begin{cases}
d S_t = \sigma_t \varphi \left(S_t\right) dW_t^1 \\
d \sigma_t = \gamma \sigma_t dW_t^2 \\
\langle W^1, W^2\rangle_t = \rho t
\end{cases}
$$
Introducing the process $J$ as
$$
J_t \equiv J\left(S_t, \sigma_t\right), \quad J \left(x, y\right) := \frac{1}{y}
\int_K^x{\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\varphi \left(u\right)}}
$$
We compute partial derivatives
\begin{align}
\partial_x J & = \frac{1}{y \varphi \left(x\right)} \\
\partial_{xx}^2 J & = - \frac{\varphi' \left(x\right)}{y \varphi \left(x\right)^2} \\
\partial_y J & = - \frac{J}{y} \\
\partial_{yy}^2 J & = \frac{2 J}{y^2} \\
\partial_{xy}^2 J & = - \frac{1}{y^2 \varphi \left(x\right)}
\end{align}
to apply Itō formula.
\begin{align}
dJ_t & = \frac{d S_t}{\sigma_t \varphi \left(S_t\right)} - J_t \frac{d \sigma_t}{\sigma_t}
+ \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{2 J_t}{\sigma_t^2} d \langle \sigma \rangle_t
- \frac{\varphi' \left(S_t\right)}{\sigma_t \varphi \left(S_t\right)^2} d \langle S \rangle_t
- 2 \frac{d \langle S,  \sigma \rangle_t}{\sigma_t^2 \varphi \left(S_t\right)}
\right] \\
& = dW_t^1 - \gamma J_t dW_t^2 + \left[\gamma^2 J_t - \rho \gamma - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t \varphi' \left(S_t\right) \right] dt \\
& = q \left(J_t\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} d \bar{W}_t + \left[\gamma^2 J_t - \rho \gamma - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t \varphi' \left(S_t\right) \right] dt
\end{align}

Noticing that $\delta \left(J_t\right) \equiv \sigma_t \, \delta \left(S_t - K\right)$, we get
$$
\varphi \left(K\right) \mathbb{E} \left[\sigma_t^2 \delta \left(S_t - K\right)
\right] = \varphi \left(K\right) \mathbb{E} \left[\sigma_t \delta \left(J_t
\right)\right] = \varphi \left(K\right)  \sigma_0 \, \mathbb{E} \left[
e^{\gamma W_t -\frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 t} \delta \left(J_t\right)\right]
$$

Let us define the probability $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$ by
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \hat{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbb{Q}} = e^{\gamma W_t^2
- \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 t}
$$
By Girsanov's theorem,
$$
\begin{cases}
    \hat{W}^1 := W^1 - \rho \gamma \cdot \\
    \hat{W}^2 := W^2 - \gamma \cdot
\end{cases}
$$
are $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$-Wiener processes with marginal covariance process $\Sigma$. The $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$-dynamics of $J$ is
$$
d J_t = d \hat{W}_t^1 - J_t \gamma_t \, d\hat{W}_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}
\sigma_t \varphi' \left(S_t\right) dt
$$
Since a linear combination of Gaussian random variables (Wiener process increments) is also Gaussian, we can rewrite that dynamics using a single $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$-Wiener process $\hat{U}$
$$
d J_t = \sqrt{q \left(J_t\right)} \, d\hat{U}_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t
\varphi' \left(S_t\right) dt; \quad q : j \mapsto \left(1 - 2 \rho \gamma j
+ \gamma^2 j^2 \right)
$$

Similarly,
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[\delta \left(S_t - K\right) \right]}{\varphi
\left(K\right)} = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\delta \left(J_t\right)}{\sigma_t}
\right]}{\varphi \left(K\right)} = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[\delta\left(J_t\right)
e^{- \gamma W_t^2 + \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 t}\right]}{\sigma_0 \varphi
\left(K\right)}
$$
We now define the probability $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$ by
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \tilde{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbb{Q}} = e^{- \gamma
W_t^2 - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 t}
$$
to get
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[\delta \left(S_t - K\right) \right]}{\varphi
\left(K\right)} = \boxed{\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right] e^{\gamma^2t}}{\sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)}}
$$

By Girsanov's theorem,
$$
\begin{cases}
    \tilde{W}^1 := W^1 + \rho \gamma \cdot \\
    \tilde{W}^2 := W^2 + \gamma \cdot
\end{cases}
$$
are $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$-Wiener processes with marginal covariance process $\Sigma$. The $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$-dynamics of $J$ is
\begin{align*}
    d J_t & = d \tilde{W}_t^1 - J_t \gamma_t \, d\tilde{W}_t^2 + 
    \left[2 J_t \gamma^2 - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t \varphi' \left(S_t\right)
    - 2 \rho \gamma\right] dt \\
    & = \sqrt{q \left(J_t\right)} \, d\tilde{U}_t + \left[q' \left(J_t\right)
    - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t \varphi' \left(S_t\right)\right] dt
\end{align*}

Let us define the $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$-martingale $\bar{\rho}$ by its dynamics
$$
d \bar{\rho}_t = - \frac{q' \left(J_t\right)}{\sqrt{q \left(J_t\right)}}
\bar{\rho} d \tilde{U}_t
$$
and initial value $\bar{\rho}_0 = 1$. We can then define another probability $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ by $\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mathrm{d} \tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} = \bar{\rho}_t$, under which $J$ has the same dynamics as under $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$, up to the drift of $\sigma$ :
$$
d J_t = \sqrt{q \left(J_t\right)} \, d\bar{U}_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t
\varphi' \left(S_t\right) dt
$$

He then introduces the process $X_t = \frac{q \left(J_0\right)}{q \left(J_t\right)} e^{\gamma^2 t}$ and notices that $X_t = \bar{\rho}_t e^{\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t{\varphi' \left(S_s\right) \sigma_s \frac{q' \left(J_s\right)}{q \left(J_s\right)}\mathrm{d}s}}$. **Until then, OK**.

**First interrogation**

**Now**, first thing he does I do not get at all is the following expression they give for the SABR density.

$$
D = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\frac{\color{blue}{q \left(J_0\right)}}{\color{red}{q \left(J_t\right)}}\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right] e^{\gamma^2t}}{\color{blue}{q \left(J_0\right)} \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)}
$$

**Blue term is fair enough, but I do not see the legitimacy of introducing the random term in red within the expectation**.

**Second interrogation**

*Admitting* this second expression for a moment and continuing the derivation, we get
\begin{align}
D & = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\frac{q \left(J_0\right)}{q \left(J_t\right)}\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right] e^{\gamma^2t}}{q \left(J_0\right) \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)} = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[X_t\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right]}{q \left(J_0\right) \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}{\mathrm{d} \tilde{\mathbb{Q}}} e^{\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t{\varphi' \left(S_s\right) \sigma_s \frac{q' \left(J_s\right)}{q \left(J_s\right)}\mathrm{d}s}}\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right]}{q \left(J_0\right) \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[e^{\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t{\varphi' \left(S_s\right) \sigma_s \frac{q' \left(J_s\right)}{q \left(J_s\right)}\mathrm{d}s}}\delta\left(J_t\right)
\right]}{q \left(J_0\right) \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[e^{\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t{\varphi' \left(S_s\right) \sigma_s \frac{q' \left(J_s\right)}{q \left(J_s\right)}\mathrm{d}s}} \middle \vert J_t = 0\right] \times \mathbb{E}^{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\delta\left(J_t\right)\right]}{q \left(J_0\right) \sigma_0 \varphi \left(K\right)}
\end{align}

Using the fact that $J$ has the same dynamics under $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, up to the different drift of $\sigma$, they cancel out $\mathbb{E}^{\hat{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\delta\left(J_t\right)\right]$ in the numerator and $\mathbb{E}^{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}} \left[\delta\left(J_t\right)\right]$ in the denominator. Remains to compute the expectation of the exponential term conditionned at $J_t = 0 \Leftrightarrow S_t = K$.

To my understanding, they compute it to be (at least approximately)
$$
e^{\frac{\sigma_0}{2}\left[\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2} \varphi' \left(S_0\right) \frac{q' \left(J_0\right)}{q \left(J_0\right)}} \color{red}{- \rho \gamma \varphi' \left(K\right)} \right]t}
$$

I interpret the first term as a freeze of the integrand at its initial value (OK if vol of vol is small, else not sure of the accuracy of it), but **have no idea where the second term comes from**.

Any idea?